# What is the difference between BrokenPipeError and ConnectionAbortedError?

Tags: javascript, python, websocket

I am playing with [eventlet's websocket](http://eventlet.net/doc/modules/websocket.html#eventlet.websocket.WebSocket.send). When I connect to a websocket from my browser, and then close the websocket from my browser, a `ConnectionAbortedError` is raised on the server side, but eventlet's documentation states that a `BrokenPipeError` should be raised.

I read Python's documentation about [BrokenPipeError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BrokenPipeError) and [ConnectionAbortedError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ConnectionAbortedError) but I don't understand the difference.

Here is the javascript code :

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://...');
socket.onmessage = function(m){console.log(m.data);};
socket.close();
```

Comment: How are you closing the websocket? Post your code.

Comment: @Barmar I am just using the chrome javascript console. The socket is closed on the client side, the exception is raised on the server side.